# SPSS calculating 50 characters or less

Tags: spss

I am new to SPSS and one of my tasks is to find out the percentage of statuses that are 50 characters or shorter and the skewness of the distribution.

Answer (score 1):

```
COMPUTE tweetLen=CHAR.LENGTH(tweet).
EXECUTE.
RECODE tweetLen (Lowest thru 50=1) 
EXECUTE.
```